# Saving a complete MMS with images and text

Tags: backup, mms

I have a Moto G Power (Android 10). I get great MMS with GIFs and words. I can save the GIF easily.

Is there a way to save the entire message (GIF *and* text)?

Google only backs up the attachment, not the words. I take a screenshot of the text but it is no longer together.
Well I managed to make excellent photos with the text included while viewing the GIF, now if I could only back them up to a second storage in case of a photos mishap!

Comment: Are you trying to transfer the complete conversation to another phone? If so, then SMS Backup & Restore app in the Play Store should handle that for you... If you are trying to save it to a local file (like on a PC), I don't have an answer for that.

Comment: I am just trying to save the animation and text together on my phone. I don't have a pc, just a phone and tablet. SMS backup + restore backs up on schedule on WIFI. I'm using cellular data.

Comment: You can do backups on demand, and over-ride the WiFi requirement and use mobile data... Easiest way is to push it to GDrive and then pull it out.

Comment: I downloaded SMS backup and restore again and backed up to one drive (not Google drive ) and it backed up the photo and the text. I still can't see them TOGETHER, but just getting first the text, then the gif, was the best I can expect I guess.  I guess I am expecting too much from a cell phone or tablet. Thanks for the help though!